# How can a struct inherits itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, c++14

```
template <bool condition>
struct when;

template <typename It, typename = void>
struct at_impl : at_impl<It, when<true>> { };

struct at_t {
    template <typename Xs, typename N>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Xs&& xs, N const& n) const;
};

constexpr at_t at{};

int main()
{
}
```

How could this program compiled? How can a struct inherits itself?!
I don't know what's going on here. Is this a new feture in c++?

Comment: You have confused yourself by failing to distinguish *templates* from *types*.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, I'm not quite familiar with templates. Could you please explain more? Why `at_impl` do not need definition before it can be derived from?

Comment: The `at_impl` template is never instantiated in your program. So there's never a type deriving from itself.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Inheritance is something that *types* do, not templates. There's nothing in your code "inheriting itself". When the template is instantiated, it results in one type which happens to inherit from a different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a struct inherits itself?

No. A struct can not inherit itself.

A struct that is an instance of a struct template can inherit another instance of the same template, as long as the parent is instantiated with different template arguments †.

`at_impl` is not a struct; it is a template.`at_impl<It, when<true>>` is an instance of the template, and it is a struct.

Note that the parent struct must be complete at the time the derived struct is instantiated. This is possible if the parent is a specialization. Your example shows neither the definition of `at_impl<It, when<true>>` specialization, nor any instantiation of `at_impl`.

---

This is analogous to functions. A function can call itself recursively, but the function arguments must change. If a function calls itself with the same arguments, then the recursion can never terminate. A function with no arguments can not be recursive ††.

Now, a template has arguments and is analogous to a function with parameters. A type has no template arguments and is analogous to a function with no parameters. Instantiating a template results in a type and is analogous to a function call.

---

† This is a necessary condition for the termination of the recursion, but not sufficient.

†† Unless the function depends on global state, but from abstract point of view, we must consider global state as an implicit argument in this context.

Answer (score 1):

`at_impl` is a `struct`/`class` template, from which a `struct`/`class` is generated.

Different template arguments to `at_impl` generate different `struct`s. Inheriting from a different `struct`/`class` is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now.